# grep inside shell script not working

Tags: bash, shell, grep

When I run this on the command line it works:

```
ls | grep -v "#$"
```

But when I do `ls | scriptname` and inside the script I have:

```
#fileformat=unix
#!/bin/bash
grep -iv '#$'
```

It's not working. Why?

[EDIT]

the reason for the first line is explained [here](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/87-Linux-shell-scripting-bad-interpreter-No-such-file-or-directory.html).

besides that even if i remove the first two lines it SHOULD work. i tried the exact same on a remote Solaris account and it did work. so is it my Fedora installation?

Comment: yes agreed, removing first 2 lines should still work, because your script is being interpreted by the default shell, almost certainly bash. BUT the `#fileformat=unix` in your file is, strictly a comment. Note that the link you include, they are refering to editing a file with the `vi` editor AND that the exact usage is `: fileformat=unix` (note the ':' char). Text like `:var=value` is vi speak for 'set a vi option', in this case, fileformat=unix means 'use only \n (LF) char at end of line NOT the DOS version of \r\n (CR,LF). Other posters are correct, you don't want #f.. at the top!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash-bang line needs to be the first line in the script. Get rid of the `#fileformat=unix`. Also make sure your script is executable (`chmod +x scriptname`). This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -iv '#$'
```

Comment: i don't know what happened but it's working now...thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `ls < scriptname` so that the output is passed to ls.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I thought about it. ;-) ... You should test your solutions before posting. Keep on posting!

Comment: @shellter - I did test it on my Mac before posting and I got the same output as running `ls | grep -v "#$"`, maybe I misunderstood the question? I do think your solution is much more flexible being able to pass in the search targets

Comment: @shellter - Ok, I take it back ;) I just looked back at where I was testing and I was totally off, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

1st off you need #! /bin/bash as the first line in your script.

Then '#$' has no meaning in the shell pantheon of parameters. Are you searching for a '#' at the end of the line? (That is OK). But if you meant '$#' but then $# is the parameter that means the 'number of arguments on the command-line'

Generally, piping a list of files to a script to acted on would have to be accomplished with further wrapper. So a bare-bones, general solution to the problem you pose might be :

```
$cat scriptname
#!/bin/bash

while read fileTargs ; do
   grep -iv "${@}" ${fileTargs}   # (search targets).
done
```

called as

```
ls | scriptname srchTargets
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: "Are you searching for a '#' at the end of the line? " Yes